# Перенос слов в названии кнопки в Андроид?

Tags: android, android-button, перенос-слов

В данный момент слова (именно слова!) переносятся (в элементах Button/TexView) как попало. Может перенестись на новую строку одна буква из слова. Речь идет как о русском так и английском языках.

Как добиться автоматически грамотного переноса (СО ЗНАКОМ ПЕРЕНОСА! (дефисом))?

Или хотя бы управляемого переноса в СЛОВАХ, с дефисом?

Т.е. типа "мягкого" переноса < wbr > ? (который здесь не работает)

Общепринятые & shy; | & #173; | u+00ad тоже не работают.

Html.fromHtml(...) применяется.

P.S. Речь идет о приложении

P.P.S. Немного помогает: \u200B
Но нет знака переноса (дефиса)

Comment: Речь о превью в АС или о приложении?

Comment: О приложении. (Спасибо, добавил это пояснение в вопрос)

Comment: android studio - IDE, редактор и отладчик кода, сама по себе никак не влияет на спобности приложений, написанных для ОС Android, переносить слова (решение проблемы будет одинаковым для любой IDE и указывать одну из них в заголовке вопроса некорректно)

Comment: Ok, Pavlofff... Но именно Андроид Студия не подсказывает решение. И именно в рамках Андроид Студии я с этим столкнулся и в ней же не нашел решения и для нее ищу решение. Таким образом Андроид Студию косвенно здесь упомянуть, думаю, вполне целесообразно... Может это решается спец. библиотекой (или спец. функцией/плагином) для Андроид Студии...

Answer (score 1):

1. Я думаю, что надо создать некий абстрактный AbstractTextView как наследника от TextView. От которого будут наследоваться свои собственные CustomTextView и CustomEditTextView.

И в зависимости от размера элемента (при вызове метода onMeasure) рассчитывать влезает ли фраза или нет и по собственному алгоритму переноса расставлять слова.

2. При этом, перенос слов это больше про русский. В современном английском использование переноса на печати практически не используется. Средняя длина английского слова не так велика, как в русском языке, например, поэтому, чтобы сохранить красоту набора, перенос в английском языке сегодня мало используется.
3. Про [алгоритм переноса](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphenation_algorithm) можно почитать на вики.
4. Вот [эта библиотека](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) поддерживает переносы текста, но больше не поддерживается.
   `DocumentView documentView = addDocumentView(new StringBuilder("Your long text content"), DocumentView.PLAIN_TEXT);
   documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);
   documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setHyphenator(new Hyphenator(HyphenPattern.PT)); // перенос
   documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setHyphenated(true);`

Но, возможно, вся эта информация будет полезной для решения задачи.